# Test secure cookie value in Jest

Tags: javascript, cookies, jestjs

I have a method that I need to test that do something and store a value in a cookie.

In addition , I have a test that executes this method and check the value in the cookie is correct.

Now , I have to turn on the secure flag of the cookie and I'm no longer see the cookie in the test.
Is there any option to fix it without just mocking a cookie value ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: _Are_ you using HTTPS?

Comment: The cookie is created in client side

Comment: @CBroe Sorry, didn't see your message. Just added a comment. Yes . I'm using HTTPS